# Im trying to remove a screw holding a part from a fanimation fan and it remains stuck no matter what. Any suggestions?

Tags: ceiling-fan, screws, bolts

I'm trying to replace some parts of a fanimation fan and inside of it there's a piece with wires inside that can't be removed unless I remove the glass cover. There are 3 screws in which I removed two of them but the 3rd one is stuck and won't unscrew (I'm worried that it has been stripped) no matter what I do. The photos include where the issue is and also the screws that were removed and the tool I used to remove them. I hope the 3 photos are enough to get assistance because this is very frustrating.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. [image][image]

[image]

enter image description here][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEVL8.jpg)https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHsp.jpg

Comment: Try using the right torx driver/bit.  You are using a hex key/driver which might work somewhat, but is not the right driver/bit.  Using the wrong bit can ruin the screw head requiring big locking pliers/cutting to remove.

Comment: you mean the screw at 3 o'clock'

Comment: does the screw turn?

Comment: Yes the screw on the right. No it doesn't turn. I bought a torn that fits into the screw but need to purchase the drill now. Wish me luck

Answer (score 1):

If the screw was overdriven, it may have stripped its threads. If so, you need to find a way to put tension on that screw while turning it... and once it's under tension it may simply pull out without needing to be turned.